# RecyclerView has no LayoutManager | Kotlin

Tags: android, xml, kotlin, android-layout, android-recyclerview

I am trying to create a CardView within a RecyclerView but I can't get it to launch since the app crashes after starting with this error "RecyclerView has no LayoutManager". I've tried to apply fixes suggested by other posts regarding the same problem but got no luck so far.

Thank you in advance.

HomeActivity.kt

```
class HomeActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_home)

    // Retrieves data from source
    val arrayList = ArrayList<PreviewCardModel>()
    arrayList.add(PreviewCardModel("Product A","500mg / 1000mg", R.drawable.image, 500))
            arrayList.add(PreviewCardModel("Product D","Sample", R.drawable.image, 5040))
            arrayList.add(PreviewCardModel("Product E","Sample", R.drawable.image, 5500))
            arrayList.add(PreviewCardModel("Product F","Sample", R.drawable.image, 2500))

    val myAdapter = CardAdapter(arrayList, this)
    recyclerView.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(this, LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL,false)
    recyclerView.adapter = myAdapter
```

CardAdapter.kt

```
import android.content.Context
import android.view.LayoutInflater
import android.view.View
import android.view.ViewGroup
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
import com.sample.appname.R
import com.sample.appname.model.PreviewCardModel
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.preview_card.view.*

class CardAdapter (private val arrayList: ArrayList<PreviewCardModel>, val context: Context) :
    RecyclerView.Adapter<CardAdapter.CardViewHolder>() {

    class CardViewHolder(itemView: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView) {

        fun bindItems (model: PreviewCardModel) {
            itemView.previewName.text = model.title
            itemView.previewDesc.text = model.desc
            itemView.previewPrice.text = model.price.toString()
            itemView.previewImage.setImageResource(model.image)
        }
    }

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): CardViewHolder {

        val view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context).inflate(R.layout.preview_card, parent, false)

        return CardViewHolder(view)
    }

    // Returns size of data list
    override fun getItemCount(): Int {
        return arrayList.size
    }
    // Displays data at a certain position
    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: CardViewHolder, position: Int) {
        holder.bindItems(arrayList[position])
        }
    }
```

activity_home.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:padding="16dp"
    tools:context=".HomeActivity">

    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recyclerView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="150dp"
        android:background="@color/browser_actions_title_color"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        />
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

This is the error I am encountering.

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.sample.appname, PID: 5333
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.sample.appname/com.sample.appname.HomeActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #54 in com.sample.appname:layout/activity_home: RecyclerView has no LayoutManager androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView{b2c2d71 VFED..... ......I. 0,0-0,0 #7f09016f app:id/recyclerView}, adapter:null, layout:null, context:com.sample.appname.HomeActivity@5dcb507
```

preview_card.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.cardview.widget.CardView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="120dp"
    android:padding="10sp"
    app:cardCornerRadius="3dp"
    app:cardElevation="3dp"
    app:cardUseCompatPadding="true">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/previewImage"
            android:layout_width="80dp"
            android:layout_height="80dp"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            android:src="@drawable/heart"
            android:contentDescription="@string/product_image" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/previewName"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/product_name"
            android:textSize="11sp"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/previewImage" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/previewDesc"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="SAMPLE"
            android:textSize="8sp"
            android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/previewName"
            tools:ignore="SmallSp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/previewPrice"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:text="@string/samplePrice"
            android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary"
            android:textSize="11sp"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent" />

</androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
```

Comment: Try to remove `android:orientation="horizontal"` from the `RecyclerView`

Comment: @Zain still no luck. It displays the same error.

Comment: Have you tried adding `app:layoutManager="androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager"` to xml ? Just for checking. Btw according to your error message the adapter is null.

Comment: I would also give a shot by replacing kotlin-synthetic with classic `findById`.

Comment: That specific error happens when a `<RecyclerView>` in layout XML has child elements inside of it, which you cannot do. The layout you've posted clearly has no children in the `<RecyclerView>`, so the issue is possibly elsewhere. Are you sure that's the current and exact layout? Are you sure that's the current and correct Exception? Are you sure you're running a current build? Do you possibly have more than one `activity_home` layout; e.g., one each for portrait and landscape, or for different Android versions, etc.?

Comment: @MikeM.you're right. I did have an auto-generated activity_home(v21) in there that I thought I deleted already.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This error occurs when you've created same layout for multiple SDK or orientation and not mentioned the view in all the layout files, say for: activity_main.xml(v21)or activity_main(land) and so on. All the layouts should contain all the views with same IDs.

FIX: I had another activity_home(v21) layout that was cause the problems. Make sure you don't have multiple layouts that will cause problems. It was detecting no LayoutManager in the v21 version layout.